# Find $f(x)$ for $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t)\sin^2 (t)\ dt$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)$ for $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t)\sin^2 (t)\ dt$

Become
$f(x)$ for $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} (t+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t)\sin^2 (t)\ dt)\sin^2 (t)\ dt$
\begin{align}
& f(x) = x + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin^2(t) dt \\
\implies &f(x) - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin^2(t) dt = x
\end{align}

I got stuck. Please help me?

Comment: @Mattos It is quite easy. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is $$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(t)\sin^2(t)dt$$ Then it is easy to see $f(x)-x$ is constant, write $f(x)=x+C$. Multiply $\sin^2(x)$ on both sides, integrate, and divide both sides by $\frac{1}{\pi}$ gives$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x\sin^2(x)dx+C\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin^2(x)dx$$which essentially gives$$C=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\pi^2}{4}+C\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: What does it mean c must be $\pi/2$ ? So f(x) satisfies what?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the equation shows that $f(x)=c+x$ for some constant $c$. So plug in  $f(x)=c+x$ and see for what values of $c$ the  equation is satisfied.  My calculations show that $c=\frac {\pi} 2$.